# Suppress blank section

Tags: crystal-reports

How do I suppress a blank section on my report? I have tried suppressing with

```
if Count({MyVariable}) > 0 then false else true
```

and

```
IF {OnLastRecord} = "" AND pagenumber=TotalPageCount
THEN TRUE
ELSE FALSE
```

What am I missing?  It is hiding the data but not the header. Another table is hiding the data and that is a very long Subreport that should be hidden if there is no value.

It almost seems like this is a bug. I've tried suppressing everything.  Shouldn't suppress blank section work?

Answer (score 0):

To suppress a blank section check the `Suppress Blank Section`. This just works.

If you want to suppress a section that contains a sub-report that seems to be empty, there are several places you can check:

- make sure `Suppress Blank Section` is checked for the section that contains *only* your subreport (otherwise it wont be an empty section)
- make sure `Suppress Blank Subreport` is checked in the Subreport section of Format Editor of the subreport
- within the subreport (open the subreport to edit, double click from your main report) go to `File | Report Options` and check `Suppress printing if no records`. This will suppress your subreport when there are no records - even if you have static elements, like text in the subreport header etc.

Comment: That worked, thank you.  I needed all three.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem the issue was the section had a box in it so was never blank. I found it worked if I put the formula in the "*Suppress (No Drill-Down)*" option for the section instead of in the "*Suppress Blank Section*" option.